# bash prompt does not show the beginning of the line

Tags: linux, bash

My shell prompt replace the beginning of long lines with <
How can I have the long lines visible on several lines ?

```
user@machine:~$
<s line is a very long one and the beggining is not visible...
```

Comment: FYI this takes all of typing `man bash<Enter>/wrap<Enter>`... ([teach a man how to fish](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/2279.html)... oh well; I guess SO is a pond as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `inputrc`

> #### `horizontal-scroll-mode` (Off)
>
> When set to On, makes readline use a single line for display, scrolling the input horizontally on a single screen line when it becomes longer
>              than the screen width rather than wrapping to a new line.

The location of that file is governed by the `INPUTRC` variable:

> #### `INPUTRC`
>
> The filename for the readline startup file, overriding the default of ~/.inputrc (see READLINE below).

(both quotes from [`man bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html))

Comment: In fact, I was on cygwin with bash version 3.2.48. An update of cygwin with bash 4.1.10 fixed the thing. Thanks a lot for the info regarding inputrc, I'll definitively keep this for later use.

Comment: Thanks for the background issues there, that is helpful to all those using Cygwin